# Android minSDKVersion e targetSDKVerion

Tags: android

Qual é a diferença entre `minSDKVersion` e `targetSDKVerion`?

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jorge,

`minSdkVersion` indica qual API mínima exigida para rodar o aplicativo.
No seu caso, `minSdkVersion="14"`, indica que não será possível rodar o aplicativo caso o usuário tenha a API anterior a 14 (Android 4.0.0).

`targetSdkVersion` indica para qual API o seu aplicativo foi desenvolvido, quando não for atribuído nenhum valor, o valor da `minSdkVersion` é assumido.

**Trecho da documentação sobre o `minSdkVersion`:**

> Cuidado: Se você não declarar esse atributo, o sistema assume um valor
>   padrão de "1", o que indica que a sua aplicação é compatível com todas
>   as versões do Android. Se o seu aplicativo não é compatível com todas
>   as versões (por exemplo, ele usa APIs introduzidas na API Nível 3) e
>   você não declarou o `minSdkVersion` adequada, então, quando instalado em
>   um sistema com um nível API inferior a 3, a aplicação irá falhar
>   em tempo de execução ao tentar acessar as APIs indisponíveis. Por
>   esta razão, é certo que declarar o nível API apropriado no atributo
>   `minSdkVersion`.

E ainda é possível indicar o `maxSdkVersion`, que significa a API máxima para rodar o seu aplicativo.

**Trecho da documentação sobre o `minSdkVersion`:**

> Aviso: Declarar este atributo não é recomendado. Em primeiro lugar,
>   não há necessidade de definir o atributo como meio de bloquear a
>   instalação de sua aplicação em novas versões da plataforma Android. Pelo projeto, as novas versões da plataforma
>   são totalmente compatíveis com versões anteriores. Sua aplicação deve
>   funcionar corretamente em uma nova versão, desde que utilize apenas APIs
>   padrão e siga as melhores práticas de desenvolvimento. Em segundo
>   lugar, note que, em alguns casos, declarando o atributo pode resultar
>   em seu aplicativo que está sendo removido dispositivos dos usuários
>   depois de uma atualização do sistema para um nível mais elevado API. A
>   maioria dos dispositivos em que seu pedido seja suscetível de ser
>   instalado receberá atualizações periódicas do sistema,
>   então você deve considerar o seu efeito sobre o seu app antes
>   de definir este atributo.

Existe uma explicação bem detalhada nesta documentação: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Então como por exemplo com o mim e target da pergunta. Não haverá problemas de compatibilidade se eu rodar num dispositivo com API 14, visto que desenvolvi para a API 19?

Comment: Exatamente. Não haverá problema, mas se tentar rodar na API 13 não funcionará.

Comment: E se eu meter min=13 e target=19 não haverá problemas de compatibilidade da app? Parece me um bocado estranho que a API 13 nada tem a ver com a 19. E se eu estou a desenvolver para 19 não tem grande lógica não haver problemas ao instalar num dispositivo com API 13.

Comment: Jorge, alterei a resposta original.

Comment: Ficou muito boa. Só mais uma perguntinha. O ideal será por min e target iguais?

Comment: O ideal é setar o minSdkVersion com o número de API mais alto utilizado na sua app.